# OpenEphyra QA API

Tags: api, nlp

I'm currently working on a project about NLIDB (natural language interfaces to databases). To process the natural language question, I need some kind of question analyzer module, which is provided by OpenEphyra. I have been working to use OpenEphyra API for a few weeks without luck. There are errors in the source code, and I don't know how to fix the errors and build the source code.

Does someone know how to use OpenEphyra API? Or is there other natural language question analyzer tools beside OpenEphyra?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OpenEphyra operates best over natural language, which means that it needs large blocks of text to be able to find any answer at all.  The default knowledge miner for data that you are inserting locally to the machine, Indri, was written in C and C++ with an interface to OpenEphyra that I have found to be shaky and error-ridden at times.  This improved greatly when I wrote a KnowledgeMiner class that used Apache Lucene to index and retrieve documents for OpenEphyra.  So if you decide to stick with OpenEphyra, it will probably work best for you to write a similar KnowledgeMiner that accesses data through a database.

That being said, you should probably consider some of the technology used by IBM Watson for Jeopardy; open-source UIMA is a good start, but Tony Pearson's blog (ibm.co/Pearson) offers a pretty good tutorial for how to build your own question-answering system backed by a database.